# Alfresco webscript text fromat line break

Tags: alfresco, web-scripting

I created an alfresco webscript and output file as xxx.get.text.ftl file. 
In the output file(xxx.get.text.ftl), I am trying to create text version of newsletter. But I am not able to get text lines with line break.
if I put

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

I am getting as

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Any Idea what could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

in my case i have page, template-instance,template and region. It turns out that when I call web script that fill the region it displays as text.But if I call full url like "www.xxx.com/news/my-news" it includes other components like template, page etc. and it turns the output to html. Because output for template or page is hard coded to text/html in surf.

Comment: What content type are you sending? And what format are you line endings in? (Mac, Unix, Windows?)

Comment: I am requesting text format, I have just plain text as above in Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

If is text try to add

```
\n
```

at the end of line

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace and especially new-line handling is always an issue for template languages because it is not clear whether the remove the new line after a closing template-tag or not. See the freemarker documentation for discussion: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html

I think you just have to add an extra newline.

Comment: by saying "I think you just have to add an extra newline." you mean add empty new line? if so, it is not working

Comment: Please post your freemarker source. Btw if you check the output with the browser verify that the response is delivered with content-Type text/plain and not text/html.

Comment: Lothar,thanks for the hint.I add new comments to my question.